# Creating form or updating an order in a Shopify App

Tags: ruby-on-rails, shopify, shopify-app

I am attempting to create an app that can update existing orders.  I can't seem to figure out out to allow editing.
Orders API:: https://help.shopify.com/en/api/reference/orders/order

I'm wondering how I would set this up.  I have my controller which fetches all Orders.  In the views I have a list of the orders, which i can then click on to display the order page in the admin dashboard.

My goal is to be able to edit the product within the Order, but that looks like it will take combing Orders and Product API (i assume),,, so for now I'm looking to simply update the Note or Name of purchaser as a start.  Just trying to start there for now.  Here's a terrible attempt at updating the name:

```
<form method="POST" action="https://#{@shop_session.url}/admin/orders.json" data-shopify-app-submit=" ">
  <input name="authenticity_token" value="<%= form_authenticity_token %>" type="hidden">
  <p>
    <%= form.label :name %>
    <%= form.text_field :shopify_order_name, class: "form-control" %>

    <%= form.submit %>
  </p>

</form>
```

I'm hoping one of you can guide me in how to correctly format the code along with the API.  There doesn't seem to be any tutorials on this aside from Shopify's API docs, which don't help me in setting this up further than I have gotten in simply displaying the orders.

Answer (score 0):

Just so you know. You cannot edit orders. Once an order is in Shopify, at most you can diddle with the notes assigned to it, and perhaps update an email.

If you want to diddle with orders, you can edit Draft Orders, which are a different beast. You can create, edit and change Draft Orders, and once you are happy with it, you can do things like send a link to the actual order to the customer asking them to pay for it, etc.

Comment: As for editing orders, I want to be able to edit the orders products within an order, which is definitely possible as there are apps that do this already - or accomplish it in some sort of way.  But do you have a suggestions on how to create a form in general and what the format should be? Maybe even for just the draft ?

Comment: You cannot edit products in an order. You can with a Draft Order. Any Apps allowing for editing orders are sophisticated in that they copy an order to a Draft Order, let you mess with it, and then return it to an Order. And that is not trivial with a form upload like you are trying.

Comment: It has been a while but i have came back to this app and it now won't load due to not being able to fetch orders anymore.  Is there some sort of new update where this is not possible? The only references i can find is that you cannot find orders past a 60 Day period, and this isn't that.  What's going on here?

Comment: To clarify (sorry this is long but please listen) --- when i remove the order fetching code in controller `@orders = ShopifyAPI::Order.find(:all)` --- it works.  if i include, it breaks and wont load at all